# Batch menu that accepts alphanumeric input

Tags: batch-file, menu, alphanumeric

so I'm trying to do a batch file that will act like a launcher program for my portable apps flash drive, everything is working just fine until I try to add alphanumeric input. What I'm mainly trying to do is, user inputs "1", opens app 1, user inputs "1H" and it opens a help screen for said app, maybe listing what that apps primary functions are. I'm mainly working with Windows 7. Here's a portion of my existing code.

```
:: Menu 12
:Antivirus
%T% ANTIVIRUS
CLS
%L%
ECHO ==================== ANTIVIRUS LAUNCHER ====================
%L%
%F%
%M%1) AVZ4                       10) Simple Machine Protect =
%M%2) ClamWin                                    11) Sophos =
%M%3) Emsisoft                          12) Spy BHO Remover =
%M%4) Kaspersky                                  13) Spybot =
%M%5) Keylogger Detector                14) Spy DLL Remover =
%M%6) McAfee                               15) Stream Armor =
%M%7) Norman                                16) Trend Micro =
%M%8) Norton                                      17) Vipre =
%M%9) Remove Fake Antivirus                   18) ViruClean =
%M%                19) Virus Total Scanner                  =
%F%
%L%
%M%20) RETURN TO PREVIOUS MENU                     21) QUIT =
%L%
SET /A XO=0
SET OX=
SET /P OX=Please Make A Selection:
SET /A XO=%XO%+%OX%
IF %XO%==1 (%S%Antivirus\avz4\avz.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==2 (%S%Antivirus\ClamWin\ClamWinPortable.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==3 (%S%Antivirus\EEK\Start Emergency Kit Scanner.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==4 (SET Menu=13 && %G%)
IF %XO%==5 (%S%Antivirus\Keylogger Detector\KL-Detector.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==6 (SET Menu=14 && %G%)
IF %XO%==7 (%S%Antivirus\Norman\Norman.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==8 (%S%Antivirus\Norton Security Scan\Engine\4.3.0.43\Nss.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==9 (%S%Antivirus\Remove Fake Antivirus\Remove Fake Antivirus.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==10 (%S%Antivirus\Simple Machine Protect\SMP.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==11 (%S%Antivirus\Sophos\sargui.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==12 (%S%Antivirus\Spy BHO Remover\SpyBHORemover.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==13 (%S%Antivirus\Spybot\SpyDLLRemover.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==14 (%S%Antivirus\Spy DLL Remover\SpybotPortable.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==15 (%S%Antivirus\Stream Armor\StreamArmor.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==16 (SET Menu=15 && %G%)
IF %XO%==17 (%S%Antivirus\VIPRERESCUE\VipreRescueScanner.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==18 (%S%Antivirus\ViruClean\ViruClean.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==19 (%S%Antivirus\Virus Total Scanner\VirusTotalScanner.exe" && %G%)
IF %XO%==20 (SET Menu=11 && %G%)
IF %XO%==21 (%E%)
%MER%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing method is using a kind of hack to force the value to be numeric, even if it wasn't to begin with.  Instead of bothering with that, you can just use text comparison:

```
SET /P SEL=Please Make A Selection:
if "%SEL%"=="1" echo AVZ4 chosen
if "%SEL%"=="1H" echo AVZ4 HELP chosen
...
```

You can add the `/I` switch if you don't care about capitalisation:

```
if /I "%SEL%"=="1H" echo AVZ4 HELP chosen
```

Given the size of your menu, adding individual IF statements for every item will make a lot of work for you, especially when you want to add or remove a menu item in the middle.  But optimising this with a smarter approach is really out of scope for your question.

Comment: Simpler is better, sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes. Thanks.